# How to make profile fields based on conditional role selection before account creation?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I'm using Drupal 7.23, autorole module and Profile2 to expand the user profile based on role.

In my setup, each role has a different set of fields available to them after they sign up.

What I'd like to do is display those field sets based on the role they select while signing up, rather than asking them to edit their profiles after account creation.

Is it possible to display the field sets based on the role radio button that is selected before the user account is created? if so, how would I do this?